# How to avoid interactivity (click etc.) on alpha transparent zones in sprites in PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, alpha, pixi.js

I loaded a hexagon.png whichs unfilled area is transparent due alpha values. When a user clicks on that one I want him only be able to click the non-transparent area to avoid overlapping events on the rectangle borders when the hexagons are aligned together. Is there any function or property that is able to do this?

Comment: You have a good answer below already, but if you need functions for calculating the hexagon points you might find stuff here useful: https://github.com/Hachitus/FlaTWorld/blob/master/src/components/map/extensions/hexagons/utils/createHexagon.js I use coordsToPixiPoints, to calculate the correct hitarea polygon based on hexagon radius... I have used the hitarea with custom hit detections (so how it works with the automatic click handling, I don't know well), but something that might be worthwhile to know too: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2487

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the hitArea of a Sprite. It can be a Rectangle, Circle, or Polygon.
For a 200 x 200 hexagon Sprite you could do something like this:

```
var points = [50,0, 150,0, 200,100, 150,200, 50,200, 0,100];
sprite.hitArea = new PIXI.Polygon(points);
```

**note this seems to be broken in the latest release. It was working in PIXI v3, and up until PIXI v4.0.3.

Comment: Is this still broken? I need to use a polygonal hitArea in a project of mine.